# Equal distribution of items (Fair Proportionment)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is a xpost from SO:
[Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929109/whole-item-distribution-by-ratio/18929284?noredirect=1#18929284)

Tagedits are more then welcome. I'm thinking this might be just as appropriate here:

### The goal:

Say I have X workers in a fruit plantation. At the plantation they're growing apples, pears and grapes.

At the end of the day, the foreman grades each workers with a ratio. The total of all ratio's is 100. The ratio is there to determine how to distribute the fruit amongst the workers at the end of the day.

How do I distribute the fruit amongst all workers so that they each get their fair share (within a certain randomness to account for integer division). Only whole fruits are divided, so integer results. And all fruits must be given out.

### What I've tried (pseudo-code):

```
for each worker:
  if applesGiven < appleStock:
    worker.give(ratio * applestock);
  if pearsGiven < pearStock:
    worker.give(ratio * pearStock);
  if grapesGiven < grapeStock:
    worker.give(ratio * grapeStock);
```

I would let the exact numer of [fruit] they where given be determined by a boolean Roundup that was initialized with a random boolean and switched after every fruit that was processed.

### Problems I ran into:

Only about 3/4 of all items are distributed
When I have an even number of fruit, the boolean gets the same value at the start of each new person.

### Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: First, it might be a good idea to edit in a link to the SO post (so as to reduce duplication of effort). Second, this sounds very much like the apportionment problem for (the US) Congress, where each state is to be given a share of the 435 Congressmen proportional to its population, no fractional Congresspeople allowed. That problem turns out to be open to many solutions, each subject to one or more objections. I'm sure you'll find many discussions of "fair apportionment" in books and on the web.

Comment: Thank you, i've edited the post accordingly and will do some research in the meantime. I couldn't come up with fair apportionment, so that didn't help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you write, "I couldn't come up with fair apportionment".

Comment: English isn't my native tongue, so I didn't know it was called like that. If you try to google fair distribution, then you get all kinds of other unrelated math topics.